# JSF 2: Accessing the object a component's value was bound to

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have simple scenario, this example comes from PrimeFaces, but I guess it applies for every tag I would use in a similar way:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{address.country}" id="#{layoutId}_country" 
    completeMethod="#{addressBean.completeCountry}" var="country"
    itemLabel="#{country.name}" itemValue="#{country}"
    converter="#{countryConverter}">
</p:autoComplete>
```

In a method of a bean (eg. addressBean.completeCounty) I have access to an AutoComplete object. What I'd like to get is the reference of its value (#{address.country}), not the value itself.

Where is that bound to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What I'd like to get is the reference of its value (#{address.country}), not the value itself.*

This question is a bit vague (it's likely the language barrier), but if I understand you correctly, you'd like to get `#{address.country}` as expression string for some reason. You can get it by [`UIComponent#getValueExpression()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getValueExpression%28java.lang.String%29) and then [`ValueExpression#getExpressionString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/Expression.html#getExpressionString%28%29).

```
public List<Country> completeCountry(String query) {
    UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    String valueEL = component.getValueExpression("value").getExpressionString();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer and deleted it because I misunderstood what was being asked.

Comment: @maple, yes I saw that. I honestly don't see how this question makes otherwise sense. If the OP intented to get the currently selected value, he would just have accessed the property directly which is way too obvious (and would have been "the value itself").

Comment: Yes, it is vague, but it was already a challenge to ask it this way :) So I'd like to get the Address object of the Country actually.

Comment: What's according to you the difference between "the reference of its value" and "the value itself"? Please show how you initially got "the value itself".

Comment: Let's suppose the inputText of the autoComplete is empty. There's no Country object after form submission but there's one defined by #{address.country}. And I'd like to get the Address object in this case.

Comment: The input of autocomplete wouldn't have been empty in first place if the `#{address.country}` is already predefinied. Isn't your converter just broken?

Comment: The converter won't run if the #{address.country} resolves to null. But it works fine if there's already a country set in the address object.

Comment: I think I understand now what happens. But the solution is unrelated to the question. Thank you for your help though, it pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: I do honestly said still not understand your concrete problem. An SSCCE (fully copy'n'paste'n'runnable example) along with a clear step-by-step use case to demonstrate your problem would have been helpful in understanding your concrete problem.